# How do I get this form to submit from angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

The top button in this example does not work in IE 8. The bottom one does.
What do I have to add to/change this example so that the top button works in IE8 as well?

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script>
         function form_controller($scope) {
            $scope.my_submit = function() {
                alert("Using angular");

                document.my_form.method = document.my_form.method_x.value;
                document.my_form.action = document.my_form.action_x.value;

                alert(document.my_form.method);
                alert(document.my_form.action);
                alert("submitting");

                document.my_form.submit();
            }
        }
        function my_submit() {

            document.my_form.method = document.my_form.method_x.value;
            document.my_form.action = document.my_form.action_x.value;

            alert(document.my_form.method);
            alert(document.my_form.action);
            alert("Using normal form : submitting");

            document.my_form.submit();
            return(false);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form ng-controller="form_controller" name="my_form">
        <input type="button" value="testing" ng-click="my_submit()"/><br/>
        <input type="button" value="testing" onclick="my_submit()"/><br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="method_x" value="post"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="action_x" value="http://www.yahoo.com"/>
    </form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please read Angular documentation around form. You submit the model using angular `$http` services. What you are doing is not angular way, see here http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <script>
>      function form_controller($scope) {
>           $scope.method_x="11";
>            $scope.action_x="ewwe";
>
>
>         $scope.my_submit = function() {
>            $scope.method_x="dfdf";
>            $scope.action_x="dfsdsddf";
>
>
>         }
>     }
>     function my_submit() {
>
>         document.my_form.method = document.my_form.method_x.value;
>         document.my_form.action = document.my_form.action_x.value;
>
>         alert(document.my_form.method);
>         alert(document.my_form.action);
>         alert("Using normal form : submitting");
>
>         document.my_form.submit();
>         return(false);
>     }
> </script> </head> <body>
> <form ng-controller="form_controller" name="my_form">
>     {{method_x}}<br>
>     {{action_x}}<br>
>
>     <input type="button" value="testing" ng-click="my_submit()"/><br/>
>     <input type="button" value="testing" onclick="my_submit()"/><br/>
>     <input type="hidden" ng-model="method_x" name="method_x" value="post"/>
>     <input  type="hidden" ng-model="action_x" name="action_x" value="http://www.yahoo.com"/>
> </form> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.js"></script>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code;

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script>
         function form_controller($scope) {
            $scope.my_submit = function() {
                alert("Using angular");

                document.my_form.method = document.my_form.method_x.value;
                document.my_form.action = document.my_form.action_x.value;

                alert(document.my_form.method);
                alert(document.my_form.action);
                alert("submitting");

                document.my_form.submit();
            }
        }
        function my_submit() {

            document.my_form.method = document.my_form.method_x.value;
            document.my_form.action = document.my_form.action_x.value;

            alert(document.my_form.method);
            alert(document.my_form.action);
            alert("Using normal form : submitting");

            document.my_form.submit();
            return(false);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form ng-controller="form_controller" name="my_form" ng-click="my_submit()">
        <input type="submit" value="testing"/><br/>
        <input type="button" value="testing" onclick="my_submit()"/><br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="method_x" value="post"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="action_x" value="http://www.yahoo.com"/>
    </form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it - we need the doc type declaration at the top, as well as a meta tag putting IE in compatibility mode. I also put class="ng-app" but I don't know if that's required.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="ng-app" ng-app> 
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
  ... rest of page
```